# Unity Editor script to fill a serialized array with children of a specified GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a serialized field of 'GameObject' that I would like to have automatically filled with children of a game object I want to specify manually.

Bonus points if I can make it impossible to manually change this array on the component, but to only display it in a 'grayed out' state.

Is this operation possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't serialize a gameobject. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Comment: @Bijan I might be misunderstanding what you're saying, but unity allows you to serialized a game object field

Comment: you might manage to store a gameobject but I don't think unity will be able to reconstruct the object tree from the serialized objects. One thing I'm certain about is `Transform` cannot be serialized because only its reference gets serialized.

Comment: for one thing, prefabs ARE the serialized object tree. those will work. but if you show us exactly what you need we can help better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
[CustomEditor( typeOf( ClassYouWantToManage ) )]
class ClassYouWantToManageEditor
{
  ClassYouWantToManage value;

  void OnEnable()
  {
   // target is the upcasted version of your managed class
   value = (ClassYouWantToManage) target;
  }

  public override void OnInspectorGUI()
  {
    // specifiedObject is the 'parent', with whos children you want to populate the array. has to be public
    if (value.specifiedObject == null)
    {
      throw new Exception ("Specified object is null");
    }

    // targetArray is the array you want to populate with children. has to be public
    // simple population alg
    value.targetArray = new GameObject[specifiedObject.transform.ChildCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < specifiedObject.transform.ChildCount; i++)
    {
      value.targetArray[ i ] = specifiedObject.transform.GetChild( i ).gameObject;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that help?

```
GameObject[] myArray;
GameObject parent;

void GetChildren()
{

    myArray=new GameObject[parent.transform.childCount];
    for (int i=0;i<parent.transform.childCount;i++)
    myArray[i]=parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;

}
```

As far as displaying it in a non-editable state - its possible but requires writing a custom Editor / Inspector for that component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Fortunately, I have this part of the problem figured out. Just need to find a way to do that when the game is not running. Basically an update function, but only when the game is not running. It would also be very helpful, if the Update function did not execute at all during runtime

Comment: Update will execute if you add [ExecuteInEditMode] tag above the line when you declare the monobehaviuour

Comment: yep, but I ONLY want it to execute then. my class contains a bunch of other functions, such as OnEnable, Start, etc. but I want it to only execute the update when the game is not playing. I could manually check whether the game is running on update, but I would rather not waste the frames

Comment: void Start() { if (Application.isPlaying) enabled=false; }